# cross browser css mask

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser

I'm trying to create a **mask** in css inside a svg with and image.

--> I'm inserting an image between 2 svg (in one file)

I've added a class **crop-image** like this

```
<image id="image-front" xlink:href="" class="crop-image" />
```

This is my class:

```
mask: url("/wp-content/themes/customtheme/assets/images/crop_image.svg");
-webkit-mask: url("/wp-content/themes/customtheme/assets/images/crop_image.svg");
height: 100%;
width: auto;
```

This code is working fine on firefox, but it doesn't work in chrome or safari. The class isn't called in my svg, but even if I copy this class manually inside my svg, it doens't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masking in CSS is done using the mask-image property, and an image has to be provided as the mask. Anything that’s 100% black in the image mask with be completely visible, anything that’s 100% transparent will be completely hidden, and anything in-between will partially mask the image. Linear and radial gradients in CSS are generated images, so they can be used as the image mask. SVGs that use the mask element can also be used as the image mask.

Answer (score 0):

According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks), `mask` is not supported outside of firefox. For Chrome and Safari, you can use `mask-image`.